# SQL LEFT JOIN not pulling intended data

Tags: sqlite

I have the below tables:

```
CATEGORIES:
id | name          | category_group  | cate_type_id
1  | Entertainment | Entertainment   | 1
2  | Electricity   | Utilities       | 8
3  | Water         | Utilities       | 8
4  | Rent          | Living Exp      | 6
5  | credit card   | Finance         | 5

BUDGET-ITEMS:
id | budget_id | cat_id | category_group| budget_yr | budget_01 | budget_02 | ... | budget_12
1  | 1         | 1      | Entertainment | 2022      | 500       |           |
2  | 1         | 2      | Utilities     | 2022      | 1500      |           |
3  | 1         | 3      | Utilities     | 2022      |           |  250      |
```

I want to pull all items from Category table with mapping budget columns.  Below is my JOIN.

```
SELECT c.id as base_id,c.name,c.category_type_id, c.category_group as base_group, b.* 
FROM category c 
LEFT JOIN budget_items b ON c.id = b.category_id 
WHERE c.category_type_id NOT IN (5) 
ORDER BY c.category_type_id, c.category_group ASC
```

I expect the below output:

```
id | budget_id | cat_id | catgroup      | budget_yr | budget_01 | budget_02 | ... | budget_12
1  | 1         | 1      | Entertainment | 2022      | 500       |           |
2  | 1         | 2      | Utilities     | 2022      | 1500      |           |
3  | 1         | 3      | Utilities     | 2022      |           |  250      |
4  | 1         | 4      | Living Exp    | 2022      |           |           |
```

However, I get like below (truncated base* columns here for space):

```
id | budget_id | cat_id | catgroup      | budget_yr | budget_01 | budget_02 | ... | budget_12
1  | 1         | 1      | Entertainment | 2022      | 500       |           |
2  | 1         | 2      | Utilities     | 2022      |           |  1500     |
3  | 1         | 3      | Utilities     | 2022      |           |           |
4  | 1         | 4      | Living Exp    | 2022      |           |           |
```

My query looks OK, not sure where it is going wrong. Does anyone see the issue?

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Edit:
I have truncated some columns for space here. the problem is the values are aligned to different budget columns. I get the columns correctly from the left table.

Edit:
Thanks to everyone who pitched in to help, I finally figured the issue was with my data. The query was actually working fine. This community is amazing.

Comment: The column names in your output don't match the aliases in the query.

Comment: Your query is using lots of columns that aren't in the tables, like `category_type_id`

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: I was going to try to paste your queries into db-fiddle.com, but with all the missing and misnamed columns, I can't.

Comment: I can't see any way that a join will move a value from the `budget_01` column to `budget_02`.

Comment: @Barmar That's what puzzles me. Let me paste the table dump shortly.

Comment: *That's what puzzles me* what? All values are where they should be.

Comment: You 1500 moved and a 250 disappeared. The sample output doesn't even match with the real data provided. Without a better description of how you think the join should behave I don't think you'll get an answer.

Comment: The accepted answer is a repeat of what you posted as a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're doing, but it seems to work as expected for me:

**Schema (SQLite v3.30)**

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `budget_id` INTEGER,
  `cat_id` INTEGER,
  `catgroup` VARCHAR(13),
  `budget_yr` INTEGER,
  `budget_01` INTEGER,
  `budget_02` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO items
  (`id`, `budget_id`, `cat_id`, `catgroup`, `budget_yr`, `budget_01`, `budget_02`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', '1', 'Entertainment', '2022', '500', null),
  ('2', '1', '2', 'Utilities', '2022', '1500', null),
  ('3', '1', '3', 'Utilities', '2022', null, '250');

CREATE TABLE cats (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `name` VARCHAR(13),
  `category_group` VARCHAR(13),
  `cate_type_id` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO cats
  (`id`, `name`, `category_group`, `cate_type_id`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Entertainment', 'Entertainment', '1'),
  ('2', 'Electricity', 'Utilities', '8'),
  ('3', 'Water', 'Utilities', '8'),
  ('4', 'Rent', 'Living Exp', '6'),
  ('5', 'credit card', 'Finance', '5');
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT c.id
     , budget_id
     , cat_id
     , catgroup
     , budget_yr
     , budget_01
     , budget_02
FROM cats c
LEFT JOIN items i ON c.id = i.cat_id
WHERE c.cate_type_id <> 5;
```

| id | budget_id | cat_id | catgroup | budget_yr | budget_01 | budget_02 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Entertainment | 2022 | 500 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | Utilities | 2022 | 1500 |  |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | Utilities | 2022 |  | 250 |
| 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m9S1B1sd6tDb6f8HzVPUQ9/2)